# browserify error cannot find module

Tags: javascript, gulp, browserify

I keep getting a browserify error 'Cannot find module 'dropdown' from /Users/user/React/src'

I dont get it because the path it shows is exactly where it is. The file is called dropdown.jsx in the src folder.

app.jsx

```
var DropDown = require('./dropdown');
```

dropdown.jsx

```
module.exports = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return <div className='dropdown'>
            ...
            </div>
    }
})
```

gulpfile.js

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var gutil = require('gulp-util');
var source = require('vinyl-source-stream');
var browserify = require('browserify');
var watchify = require('watchify');
var reactify = require('reactify');

gulp.task('default', function(){
    var bundler = watchify(browserify({
        entries: ['./src/app.jsx'],
        transform: [reactify],
        extension: ['.jsx'],
        debug: true,
        cache: {},
        packageCache: {},
        fullPaths: true
    }));

    function build(file){
        if (file) gutil.log('Recompiling ' + file);
        return bundler
            .bundle()
            .on('error', gutil.log.bind(gutil, 'Browserify Error'))
            .pipe(source('./build/main.js'))
            .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
    }
    build();
    bundler.on('update', build);
});
```